# SimpleDateFormat behaves differently in different timezones JVM

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I am following the below code to create a Date object on specified dateTime with a specified Timezone.
Note: I haven't set any timezone for jvm; But testing this code with different linux server timezones.

```
    String date = "20121225 10:00:00";
    String timeZoneId = "Asia/Calcutta";
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);

    DateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss z");
                //This date object is given time and given timezone
    java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormatLocal.parse(date + " "  
                     + timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT));

    if (timeZone.inDaylightTime(parsedDate)) {
        // We need to re-parse because we don't know if the date
        // is DST until it is parsed...
        parsedDate = dateFormatLocal.parse(date + " "
                + timeZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
    }
```

Now parsedDate object behaves differently 
**When my jvm Server is running in IST** 
parsedDate.getTime()  -- 1356409800000 
parsedDate.toString() -- Tue Dec 25 10:00:00 IST 2012
in GMT  --- 12/25/2012 04:30:00 GMT
**When my jvm Server is running in EST** 
parsedDate.getTime()  -- 1356422400000  
parsedDate.toString() -- Tue Dec 25 03:00:00 EST 2012
in GMT  --- 12/25/2012 08:00:00 GMT

My both system times are in sync 
Mon Dec 24 10:30:04 EST 2012 
Mon Dec 24 21:00:48 IST 2012 
I am expecting in both machine i should get the same GMT time.
What was wrong here?

Comment: Can we see full code? Your code right now not showing any System.outs

Comment: The machine are only in sync when they have the same GMT time.  Try using System.currentTimeMillis() on both machines. This will give you  the GMT time regardless of time zone settings. If these are not the same you have to fix it.

Comment: BTW Three letter code are not unique.  There is an EST in the USA, Europe, Brazil and Australia.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In fact it is not two different machine. I just changed timezone of single machine and i restarted my applications.

Comment: In that case, the GMT times should be the same.  I suspect the EST is time in the USA in this case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I have set America/New_York in my linux box for EST

Comment: So if you set the timezoen with setTimeZone instead of appending it to the String and trying to parse it back, it should ignore your default timezone and use whatever you give it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short-name is not a good way to identify a time-zone, because it's not unique; [the Javadoc for `java.util.TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) gives the example that "'CST' could be U.S. 'Central Standard Time' and 'China Standard Time'".

More generally . . . instead of passing the time-zone as a string, so that your `DateFormat` has to parse it, it makes more sense to just tell your `DateFormat` what the time-zone is, by using the `TimeZone` instance that you already have:

```
    DateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatLocal.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormatLocal.parse(date);
```

(This will also take care of daylight-savings time automatically, to the extent that that's possible.)

Comment: I am trying your solution currently. Could you please tell me in your answer how i will take care of daylight-savings without checking "timeZone.inDaylightTime(parsedDate)" at the maximum?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: Because you've passed in `timeZone` to your `dateFormatLocal` instance, it already knows everything about daylight-savings time, so it will already infer it if appropriate. (To the extent possible. One consequence of daylight-savings time is that certain timestamps are genuinely ambiguous, because they occur shortly before a DST transition and then again shortly after it. But there's absolutely nothing you can do about that.)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is that you are attempting to parse the IST and it has different meanings depending on what you default "location" is.

```
Time Zone Abbreviation  Zone Description    Relative UTC
IST     Irish Summer Time   UTC+01
IST     Israeli Standard Time   UTC+02
IST     Iran Standard Time  UTC+0330
IST     Indian Standard Time    UTC+0530
```

If your location is Indian it treats IST as you expect, but if you use the USA, it guesses a different time zone.

The solution is to not use three letter timezone and set them explicitly.

```
String date = "20121225 10:00:00";
String timeZoneId = "Asia/Calcutta";
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);

DateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatLocal.setTimeZone(timeZone);

Date parsedDate = dateFormatLocal.parse(date);
```

http://www.worldtimezone.com/wtz-names/wtz-ist.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick bit of [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) script to demonstrate how using an abbreviated timezone name is a problem and that results will vary according to the local environment, and especially the local default `TimeZone`.

Say you want to parse `2015-02-20T17:21:17.190EST`, and you consider EST = *Eastern Standard Time* in the US East Coast sense, so New York City time.  You therefore expect the epoch time to be exactly `1424470877190`, or `GMT: Fri, 20 Feb 2015 22:21:17.190 GMT` since this `EST` is `GMT-0500`.  Here's a test script that shows how the current default `TimeZone` effects how `EST` is interpreted.

```
import java.util.*
import java.text.*

SimpleDateFormat sdf

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"))
printDefaultTimeZone()

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz")

checkTime(sdf.parse("2015-02-20T17:21:17.190EST").getTime())
checkTime(sdf.parse("2015-02-20T17:21:17.190-0500").getTime())

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))
printDefaultTimeZone()

// same SDF

checkTime(sdf.parse("2015-02-20T17:21:17.190EST").getTime())
checkTime(sdf.parse("2015-02-20T17:21:17.190-0500").getTime())

printDefaultTimeZone()

// new SDF
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz")

checkTime(sdf.parse("2015-02-20T17:21:17.190EST").getTime())
checkTime(sdf.parse("2015-02-20T17:21:17.190-0500").getTime())

void printDefaultTimeZone() {
    println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName() + ":" +     TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() / 3600 / 1000)
}

void checkTime(long time) {
    println(time + (time == 1424470877190L ? ": CORRECT" : ":"))
}
```

Output:

`Eastern Standard Time (New South Wales):10
1424413277190:
1424470877190: CORRECT
Eastern Standard Time:-5
1424413277190:
1424470877190: CORRECT
Eastern Standard Time:-5
1424470877190: CORRECT
1424470877190: CORRECT`

In the above output, the unexpected/incorrect datetime is `1424413277190 = GMT: Fri, 20 Feb 2015 06:21:17.190 GMT`, which is *11* hours earlier than the parsed `EST` time (in this case the `Australia/Sydney` variant of `EST`), because daylight-savings time applies to that date.

So you can see that the interpretation of `EST` depends on the default `TimeZone` at the time of its *construction*.  In the first two conversion batches, the default `TimeZone` was `Australia/Sydney`, which is itself abbreviated as `EST`, so Java interprets the abbreviation as just that.  Not until after the new SDF is constructed after the default TZ has changed do we see the abbreviation applied as-expected.

As an alternative to setting the default timezone, you could also set a `Calendar` instance on the SDF:

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz")
sdf.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"), new Locale("en_US")))
```

This will have the effect of interpreting `EST` as was originally expected.