# SimpleDateFormat returning wrong time

Tags: java, kotlin, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a date/time string with SimpleDateFormat but the output I'm getting is an hour later than expected.

**Code**

```
fun formatDate(dateString: String): String {
    val locale = Locale.ENGLISH
    val time = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy", locale).parse(dateString)?.time

    return SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", locale).format(time)
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
fun shouldFormatDate() {
    val dateString = "Wed Mar 31 23:13:44 +0000 2010"
    val expected = "31/03/2010 23:13"

    assertThat(formatDate(dateString)).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

**Output**

```
expected: 31/03/2010 23:13
but was : 01/04/2010 00:13
```

I tried using ISO-8601 time zone formatting (X instead of Z) but it didn't work either.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: 10 minutes later than expected would be 23:23, no? The 1-hour offset indicates a time zone problem.

Comment: Your input define a timezone offset to GMT of `+0000` - your output uses the timezone offset in effect on `2010-03-31 23:12GMT` in the `ENGLISH` timezone, which is `+0100`, which is one hour later than GMT

Comment: @MonopoleMagnet yes you're right, it's an hour late, not 10 minutes. I've edited the question

Comment: @ThomasKläger thank you. Please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input define a timezone offset to GMT of `+0000` - for the input the locales timezone doesn't matter.

Your output however uses the timezone offset in effect on `2010-03-31 23:12 GMT` in the `ENGLISH` locale timezone. On first of April 2010 the `ENGLISH` locale uses Daylight Savings Time, which has a timezone offset `+0100`, meaning is one hour later than GMT.

Answer (score 0):

You're providing incorrect time zone in the `dateString` which should be expected as two hours later that will differ in two days in sum (difference between 31/03 & 01/04); so to make your test work you need to change the time zone from +0000 to +0200 as below:

```
@Test
fun shouldFormatDate() {
    val dateString = "Wed Mar 31 23:13:44 +0200 2010"
    val expected = "31/03/2010 23:13"

    assertThat(formatDate(dateString)).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

> **UPDATE**

The TimeZone in the `dateString` variable depends on the TimeZone of the local machine your run this test on; and that is the reason that **+0100** works with you, but not me, that is because I am in place with a TimeZone of GMT+200 and most probably you are in a place that is GMT+100.

To verify that, try to change the time zone of your local machine to something that is different than yours, and run the test, you would find it fails.

In order to make your test independent of your computer's time zone, then you need to explicitly set it; for instance, I will pick a time zone of "Australia/Sydney" which is GMT+11, then to use [`TimeZone.setDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075373/simpledateformat-behaves-differently-in-different-timezones-jvm) method to override your computer's time zone.

**Code**

```
fun formatDate(dateString: String): String {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney")) // (GMT+11:00)
    val locale = Locale.ENGLISH
    val time = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy", locale).parse(dateString)?.time

    return SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", locale).format(time)
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
fun shouldFormatDate() {
    val dateString = "Wed Mar 31 23:13:44 +1100 2010"
    val expected = "31/03/2010 23:13"

    assertThat(formatDate(dateString)).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

Also you may have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075373/simpledateformat-behaves-differently-in-different-timezones-jvm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zain. That input stream is just a copy and paste from a real value I'm receiving from the Twitter API so there's not that much I can do. But for the sake of passing the test I changed the time zone from +0000 to +0100 and it worked

Comment: @92AlanC welcome man, but something weird I guess, +0100 doesn't work for me though; happy you got it anyways

Comment: Hi @92AlanC I got why +0100 is working with you but not mine, you must be in a place that is GMT+100 .. please check updated answer